Anime about a mage taught by a spider
A boy saves or stops from killing a spider which turns out to be a divine beast of sorts. The creature teaches him magic since he is having a hard time learning on his own. He is part of a class that are misfits and they are attacked by a swarm of monsters at school, where they have to fight and summon monsters/familiars to fight too. I believe the spider was blue in color but I can't find it anywhere.

In roughly which year did you watch this? Also, was it a series or a movie?

I watched it about 2 years ago or less, it was a series k think. Kinda similar to a lot of the works from sentai studio and/or aniplex studio. There was like a competition they were training for to stay in to finish the program to become adventures. There was a scene where if they were to give up they'd break their talisman of sorts.
